# Summarizing Attribute Table Based on Condition

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, dissolve, statistics, one-to-many

I have a one-to-many joined table (i.e. duplicated AssetIDs with other different attributes), and I would like to consolidate the table (20 records) into one single record.

However, when using Summarize it takes the max compare score (3), but it always takes the lowest near_dist (0.015821 instead of 0.215665)

I have tried the summary statistics tool and dissolve, but cannot get the 2 conditions correct.

Comment: Summarize should work.  You probably need to export the joined table to a new table before summarizing.  Sometimes joins have strange behavior in arcgis

Comment: @jbalk I already exported to a new table. However, when using Summarize it takes the max compare score (3), but it always takes the lowest near_dist (0.015821 instead of 0.215665)

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify that.  You're asking to find the max of the compare score and min of the near_dist and that is 3 and 0.015821.  If you want the max compare score, then the min of the near_dist with max compare score, that's asking something different that your question is currently asking.  You'll need a multi step process - first find max compare score then filter based on that score, then find min near_dist from the filtered records and store it in another table along with the leaks_join_field, then dissolve your records based on the leaks_join_field.

Comment: Then join your second table with the min near_dist back to the output based on the leaks_join_field.

Comment: You could also use a search cursor if you're familiar with arcpy

Answer (score 1):

1. Dissolve your table on Leaks_join_field and keep for last step
2. Summarize your initial table on Leaks_join_field, keeping max of COMPARE_SCORE
3. Join the summarize result back to the initial table on Leaks_join_field
4. Add a definition query to the effect of 'main_table.COMPARE_SCORE = sum_table.COMPARE_SCORE'
5. Summarize the filtered table on Leaks_join_field, keeping min of MAINS_NEAR_DIST
6. Join the output of the second summarize back to the initial table on Leaks_join_field
7. Change the definition query to 'main_table.COMPARE_SCORE = sum_table.COMPARE_SCORE AND main_table.MAINS_NEAR_DIST = sum_table_2.MAINS_NEAR_DIST' - now you're left with your initial table filtered down to the records you want.
8. Export the filtered table to a new table.
9. Use the 'Join Field' tool to join the COMPARE_SCORE and MAINS_NEAR_DISTANCE fields from the filtered table to the dissolved table from the first step.  Now you have one record for each Leaks_join_field with its max compare score and min near distance per max compare score.

**If your table does not have geometry, skip step 1 and step 9**

Comment: What if the table does not have a Geometry field?

Comment: @fatih_dur Then you don't need to first or last step